# Current accepted/preferred handling for browsers with javascript disabled

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form I am creating and due to the sensitiveness of it, I have a fair bit of javascript validation going on and I can not allow a user to start on the form if JS is not enabled.  Back in the day I would throw a notice on using NOSCRIPT tags.  I see they are still  ok to use in HTML5, but they seem to be on the way out.  Is there a new/preferred way of handling a situation like this?

Thanks.

Comment: If the form is truly sensitive, **DO NOT** rely on JavaScript to validate it. Any kind of validation done on the client side can be easily bypassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With more HTML5 stuff, JavaScript isn't required for quite as much. For instance, form validation doesn't need JS anymore. Audio/Video doesn't require JavaScript or Flash anymore. And so on.

However, `<noscript>` remains the most reliable way to inform people that JavaScript is needed for certain features. The alternative is to just put the "JavaScript is needed" text in the page, and use JavaScript to remove it.

Comment: I went with this and styled the noscript tag to completely cover the form so no one can get to it, works great.  I have server side validation in place and am using MVC unobtrusive for most of the client side, which I believe (don't quote me) will still work even with JS disabled.  Either way, all bases are now coverd.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have done this with a redirection prior to the page.

Something like window.location() to your form and them a meta-refresh tag to a page saying it doesn't support it.

The problem is if there is no JavaScript how do you hide or prevent things on the page.

You could do what I suggested on the same page.  Have a meta refresh load by default and then have the javascript stop it.

Or perhaps have javascript set a hidden variable and then you can block the form server side.

Just some options. Other than using NOSCRIPT tags but those are probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

You should always provide validation on the server-side and return any validation errors w/o javascript. Javascript validation should never be relied on as actual data validation.

With that said, you could simply render the form with `disabled` attributes on the inputs and no `action` for the `form` and a `noscript` message, then use javascript to add the action to the form and remove the disable atributes.

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="something" id="myinput1" disabled />
 <input type="submit" id="sbmtbtn" disabled />
</form>
<noscript>You must have Javascript!</noscript>
<script>
  document.getElementById('myform').setAttribute('action', '/formpost/url');
  document.getElementById('myinput1').removeAttribute('disabled');
  document.getElementById('sbmtbtn').removeAttribute('disabled');
  // You get the picture  
</script>
```